# ImageProcessing::Error when passing crop argument to variant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rails-activestorage

I am having a model with `has_one_attached :file` that I want to process with a custom `crop` parameter. The attached file is a photo in jpg format that I use for testing.

Before, I was scaling and cropping images this way, which works as intended.

```
my_model.file.variant(resize_to_fill: [1440, 560, { gravity: 'Center' }])
```

Now I wanted to change the center / focus point for cropping the image to a custom position. The plain imagemagick command would be `convert input.jpg -crop 1440x560+580+120 output.jpg`, working as intended on the command line.

The docs state that you can pass almost any imagemagick commant to `.variant()`, which lead me to try this:

```
my_model.file.variant(crop: '1440x560+580+120')
```

This raises the following error:

```
ImageProcessing::Error - Source format is multi-layer, but destination format is
single-layer. If you care only about the first layer, add `.loader(page: 0)` to
your pipeline. If you want to process each layer,
see https://github.com/janko/image_processing/wiki/Splitting-a-PDF-into-multiple-images
or use `.saver(allow_splitting: true)`.
```

I read the manual of image_processing and understand how the pipeline works, but I am missing the part of where/how to adapt the pipeline through `.variant()` in order to get a result.

Am I doing something wrong here or am I just missing some simple part? Otherwise I'd go the way of writing it raw with an image_processing pipeline and work around it.

My environment consists of:

- rails - v6.0.2.2
- mini_magick gem - v4.10.1
- image_processing gem - v1.10.3
- ImageMagick 7.0.8-66

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `my_model.file.variant(combine_options: { crop: '1440x560+580+120')`

Comment: That helps, thank you! It does not solve my cropping as I guess I'm doing something else wrong, but that will be part of another question if I can't figure it out myself.